# Is it possible to have SageMaker output Objective Metrics during a training job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

In the SageMaker hyper parameter tuning jobs, you can use a RegEx expression to parse your logs and output a objective metric to the web console. Is it possible to do this during a normal training job?

It would be great to have this feature so I don't need to look through all the logs to find the metric.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your suggestion! We will incorporate your feedback into our roadmap planning and prioritize this feature accordingly. As always, we deliver a feature as fast as we can if we see strong customer needs in it.

Thanks for using Amazon Sagemaker !!!

Comment: Thats awesome. I also had another suggestion from another comment. Maybe you could add this one to your scoring system as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333159/is-it-possible-to-hit-endpoints-hosted-in-sagemaker-besides-invocations/51349590#51349590

Comment: I was thinking about this today. It would be really handy if you could get these Objective metrics in the response using the AWS CLI or using any of the SDKs as well as having it in the web console.