# Is it possible to hit endpoints hosted in SageMaker besides /invocations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Using the aws sagemaker cli tools it's possible to invoke endpoint that are hosted in sagemaker using a command like:

```
aws sagemaker-runtime invoke-endpoint --body file://container/local_test/payload.json \
--endpoint-name $(DEPLOYMENT_NAME)-staging \
--content-type application/json \
--accept application/json \
output.json
```

By default, this command goes to the `/invocations` endpoint. Is it possible to go to a different endpoint? For example, if I implemented a `health-report` endpoint? It's definately possible to make one as in the [BYOM example](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/container/decision_trees/predictor.py). I'm just not sure how I'd access it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently [sagemaker-runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker-runtime/index.html) has a single invoke-endpoint method.
Calling other REST resources is most likely doable if you'll call the endpoint URL yourself over HTTP (that is without using aws [sagemaker-runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker-runtime/index.html)), however, you'll probably need to take care of the required sigv4 authentication header.

Answer (score 1):

/invocations is not a SageMaker Endpoint, it's a HTTP request path where the prediction request is handled.

See documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint.html

Request syntax:
POST /endpoints/EndpointName/invocations HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: ContentType
Accept: Accept

To your endpoint, the request is like:
POST /endpoints/$(DEPLOYMENT_NAME)-staging/invocations HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: ContentType
Accept: Accept